# tkinter install on ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.12

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to run this example in a .venv with python 3.12 on my ubuntu 18.04 machine :

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/multiprocess_sgskip.html

Note I have donwloaded pyhton 3.12 from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.0/Python-3.12.0.tgz and have build from source.

I get the following error message :

```
FigureCanvasAgg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown
```

and so I have updated the code with

```
import tkinter
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

and get this error :

```
    import tkinter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

When I use :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

I get the message :

```
python3-tk is already the newest version (3.6.9-1~18.04).
```

I just to do not how to install python3-tk for python 3.12.

EDIT :

Following :

I have uninstalled 3.12.0 and have :

- installed `tk-dev`
- installed 3.12.2 from source

And it still does not work.

```
Python 3.12.2 (main, Mar 18 2024, 15:59:21) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
>>> exit()

user@user-Precision-T3610:/usr/local/bin$ apt list tk-dev
Listing... Done
tk-dev/bionic,now 8.6.0+9 amd64 [installed]

user@user-Precision-T3610:/usr/local/bin$ cd /usr/local/lib/python3.12/tkinter/

user@user-Precision-T3610:/usr/local/lib/python3.12/tkinter$ ls
colorchooser.py  constants.py  dnd.py         font.py      __main__.py    __pycache__      simpledialog.py  ttk.py
commondialog.py  dialog.py     filedialog.py  __init__.py  messagebox.py  scrolledtext.py  tix.py
```

Comment: The OS-provided `python3-tk` package is built for the OS Python package (looks like 3.6). It won't help you. To get Tkinter for the Python you compiled, you need the Tk headers to be available at build time. See the linked dupe, install the listed packages (make sure to include `tk-dev`) and then rebuild Python.